# python: Connect computers on different networks using twisted

Tags: python, networking, tcp, twisted

I apologize in advance for my poor terminology in networking as I am very new to it.  I just downloaded the twisted library for python and used it to make a simple chat server and client.  Is there a way to allow the client and server to connect from different networks (as in, can my friend connect to my server from his house)?  My existing code uses: `reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)` for the server and `reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8000, factory)` for the client.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's not a Python issue. You can surely use Twisted for that but you need to make sure that both computers can reach each other (or at least one can connect to the other). You need to read a little bit about TCP/IP and routing. If the other party is behind a firewall or home router you need to enable either port forwarding on that router or implement some kind of "NAT traversal".

Comment: to test what ofrommel said, tell your friend your ip (lets say its 133.35.50.90), and he should go to his browser and type http://133.35.50.90:8000  in the url field,if it works then you are all set. Otherwise you have to do port forwarding over port 8000 as ofrommel said, this way people will be able to access your computer's port 8000 from outside. Easiest way to find your IP is to go to a website like https://www.whatismyip.com/ and write it down.

Comment: @EmmetB As I understand so far, it is possible to connect a tcp server over different networks, but my firewall prevents me form doing this, and so I need to tell my router to allow a port to connect to my computer.  Could you please explain how to do this.